# CollectionView Grouping with Observables

Tags: xamarin.forms, grouping, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged, collectionview

Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping) example to create a grouping for CollectionView, I notice that none of the properties are INotifyPropertyChanged, nor is the base class an ObservableCollection.

While the latter is easy to fix by changing List to ObservableCollection:

```
public class AnimalGroup : ObservableCollection<Animal>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public AnimalGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<Animal> animals) : base(animals)
    {
       Name = name;
    }

    private string _someOtherPropertyIWantToChangeAtRuntime = "hey";
    public string SomeOtherPropertyIWantToChangeAtRuntime { get => _someOtherPropertyIWantToChangeAtRuntime, set => SetProperty(ref _someOtherPropertyIWantToChangeAtRuntime, value); }
}
```

It isn't clear how to make Name, or any other property (e.g. SomeOtherPropertyIWantToChangeAtRuntime), I want to associate with the group as an INotifyPropertyChanged. Treating it is as a normal class by adding the interface to base causes this warning:

> Base interface 'INotifyPropertyChanged' is redundant because AnimalGroup inherits 'ObservableCollection'

Yet, there is nothing for the setter to call, such as SetProperty(ref _name, Value) and the existing PropertyChanged object is just for monitoring a group's collection changes. It isn't invokable, just handleable.

If I ignore the warning and implement INotifyPropertyChanged anyway (and name my event PropChanged to avoid colliding with ObservableCollection.PropertyChanged),

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T backingStore, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "", Action onChanged = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
        return false;

    backingStore = value;
        
    onChanged?.Invoke();
        
    PropChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    return true;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropChanged;
```

and let my ViewModel manage the value of SomeOtherPropertyIWantToChangeAtRuntime, the bound `<Label>` never sees any changes.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AnimalGroups}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding Name}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                        FontSize="24.44" 
                        TextColor="Black" 
                        FontAttributes="Bold" 
                        Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding SomeOtherPropertyIWantToChangeAtRuntime}" FontSize="15" 
                        TextColor="Black" 
                        Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.FindGroupAndChangeTextCommand, Source{x:Reference thisPageName}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
...
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<AnimalGroup> AnimalGroups {get; private set;}

public ICommand FindGroupAndChangeTextCommand {get; private set;}
public void FindGroupAndChangeText(string name)
{
    var group = AnimalGroups.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == name);
    if (group != null)
        group.SomeOtherPropertyIWantToChangeAtRuntime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

ViewModel()
{
    AnimalGroups = LoadData(); // not shown
    FindGroupAndChangeTextCommand = new Command(FindGroupAndChangeText);
}
```

The result is that the label remains "hey" (which is the default value) and never changes even though I can see that the above command fires and the code finds the group and sets the text.

Comment: ObservableCollection has an OnPropertyChanged method

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. The ObservableCollection does have PropertyChanged but it only fires when items are added and removed. This has nothing to do with what I need.

Comment: I do understand, and you should be able to call OnPropertyChanged in your property setters

Comment: Now I get it. The setter works like this: set {_propname= value; OnPropertyChanged(newPropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Propname)));}

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jason, `ObservableCollection` has inherited `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface , So you will get the warning

> Base interface 'INotifyPropertyChanged' is redundant because AnimalGroup inherits 'ObservableCollection'

And please see following screenshot about `ObservableCollection<T>`.
[image]

If you want to change the item at the runtime like this GIF.

[image]

Based on your code. I add two properties in the `Animal` class. For achieve the change the text of properties at the runtime, we can achieve the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Animal` class. Here is `AnimalGroup.cs`

```
    public class AnimalGroup : ObservableCollection<Animal>
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public AnimalGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<Animal> animals) : base(animals)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

       
    }

    public class Animal : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        string animalName;
        public string AnimalName
        {
            set
            {
                if (animalName != value)
                {
                    animalName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("AnimalName");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return animalName;
            }
        }

        string animalArea;
        public string AnimalArea
        {
            set
            {
                if (animalArea != value)
                {
                    animalArea = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("AnimalArea");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return animalArea;
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

For testing click the command, I achieve the `MyAnimalViewModel.cs` like following code.

```
  public class MyAnimalViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<AnimalGroup> AnimalGroups { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<AnimalGroup>();

        public ICommand FindGroupAndChangeTextCommand { protected set; get; }
        public MyAnimalViewModel()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Animal> ts = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
            ts.Add(new Animal() { AnimalArea = "Asia", AnimalName = "cat" });
            ts.Add(new Animal() { AnimalArea = "Asia", AnimalName = "dog" });

            ObservableCollection<Animal> ts2 = new ObservableCollection<Animal>();
            ts2.Add(new Animal() { AnimalArea = "Eourp", AnimalName = "keep" });
            ts2.Add(new Animal() { AnimalArea = "Eourp", AnimalName = "gggg" });
            AnimalGroups.Add(new AnimalGroup("Animal1", ts));
            AnimalGroups.Add(new AnimalGroup("Animal2", ts2));


            FindGroupAndChangeTextCommand = new Command<Animal>((key) =>
            {
                key.AnimalName = "testggggg";
            });
         }
    }
```

I notice you want to achieve the group for CollectionView. Here is my edited layout.

```
  <ContentPage.Content>

        <CollectionView x:Name="MyCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding AnimalGroups}" IsGrouped="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                           BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                           FontSize="Large"
                           FontAttributes="Bold" >
                         
                    </Label>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label 
                        Text="{Binding AnimalArea}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                        FontSize="24.44" 
                        TextColor="Black" 
                        FontAttributes="Bold" 
                        Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding AnimalName}" FontSize="15" 
                                TextColor="Black" 
                                 Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                  <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" 
                                                           Command="{ Binding BindingContext.FindGroupAndChangeTextCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=MyCollectionView} }"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                                           />
                                  </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is layout background code.

```
 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new MyAnimalViewModel();
        }
}
```

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Your example updates items within a group. I want to update items associated with the group itself. For example "Animal1 - a corvid subtype", then click on it and change it to "Animal1 - a hominid subtype"

Comment: You do not have `CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate`, Header and data in the same item? Could you give me a screenshot about your data struct.

Comment: That is true. My child items are rendered horizontally and I couldn't get the regular grouping metaphor to do that. So my groups are handled by a vertical CollectionView and items are a horizontal CollectionView in the former's ItemTemplate. Jason helped me solve my posted problem.

Comment: By the way, I'm uncertain how to mark this answered.

Comment: Click the “✔” in the upper left cornert of answer like this screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/ynLesOT

Comment: But this isn't the answer. Answer is above in the discussion I had with Jason in the comments.

Comment: You can make an conclusion about above comments, then post an new answer, mark the new answer by yourself.